# MongoDB Realm - Block data leaks

Tags: realm, mongodb-realm

I am in the stage of setting up MongoDB Realm sync with Schemas but I have a question regarding data breaches.
My schemas looks like this:

```
User {
  id
  name
  groups[] (ids)
}

Group {
 id
 name
 members[] (users - Inverse Relationship)
}
```

I would like the user to login and receive their user data which includes the groups they are members of. How can I define the sync rules (or another way?) to stop anyone reverse engineering my app code and change the partition (group ID) and get access to other groups?

Comment: *to stop anyone reverse engineering* - you can't, welcome to coding. Also, the chances of that are extraordinarily low. You could encode your partition keys within your app and decode them before use (so they are live and not hard coded). The question however is way too vague and we don't know your coding platform. Please take a moment and review [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)